# How can I discover who's checked out a file in ClearCase?

Tags: clearcase

I use ClearCase.  How can I find out who's checked out a given file?

Comment: That question is way too vague...

Comment: so vague, it's not a real question as it stands...

Comment: Edited for clarity, given the clearcase tag.  I *think* my interpretation is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That kind of request is often prompted when you try to `rmname` (<kbd>DEL</kbd>) a file through the GUI.

If the file is checked-out in any other branch or any other view... the GUI will refuse to `rmname` the file!

To quickly see where the file is checked-out, try a

```
ct lsvtree myFile
```

and look (or grep) for "`CHECKEDOUT`" string.

You will se one or several line like:

```
path\to\myFile@@\main\aBranch\CHECKEDOUT view "aViewTag"
```

But remember: you can also force a rmname through the CLI (Command-Line Interface) cleartool.

Assuming you are in the correct path of the file:

```
cleartool co -nc .
cleartool rmname -force myFile
cleartool ci -nc .
```

the `-force` option (not available through GUI) will allow you to rmname your file even if it is already checked-out in another view/branch.

Answer (score 0):

Just do a *cleartool lsco* on the file element:

```
%cleartool lsco <element_name>
```

Comment: That is not the answer i'm looking for .. I want to know in anyof the view(s) (view(s) might have been created from different branches) the particular file is checkout

Comment: That's what lsco does, what the man page of lsco says for the default option is:"The listing includes all checkouts for the specified elements,including checkouts made in any view by any user". You can provide -long option to get also view to which the element was checkedout